# Nothings works when Clicking on login page. Ubuntu 20.04LTS?

Tags: 20.04, login

I have recently installed ubuntu 20.04 LTS in the virtual box. When booted, in login page when I try to click on the user or icons on the top right corner nothing responding. I clicked every where but nothing is working. I even tried to open terminal `Ctrl+Alt+f3` .But still not opening. Tried closing the windows start ubuntu again from the virtual box but still stuck in the login page. Need help as to how to get past this page.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your release(s).  Ubuntu uses *yy* releases only for specialist *snap* based releases for IoT appliances/devices or cloud based use (having done so since 2016). Main releases use *yy.mm* such as used by server & desktops releases.  *Whilst it's probable you mean 20.04 LTS (as tagged), it's best if we're not making assumptions but are told; as you mention Ubuntu 20 twice and that's closest to Ubuntu Core 20 which has the longer supported life too*

Comment: I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS . I'm very new to this. The issue I'm facing is when u logout... After getting the login screen when clicking on the username nothing is happening like it's not showing any password field or anything.. I even tried to click "not listed" ,human and other icons but still nothing is happen not getting any drop down menus.  I even tried to open terminal with ctrl+alt+F2 or f3 still in the same place.. I had to reinstall the ubuntu and enable auto login and disable auto lock and all... But when I logout still facing same issue

Comment: Please amend your question to reflect Ubuntu 20.04 LTS  (not Ubuntu 20lts).

Comment: Yes I did, Thanks for the suggestion. Very new to this forum and I'm not sure how things